# user_id 別の最新レコードを集計する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

## 概要

Railsでviewに渡すためのActiveRecord::Relationオブジェクトを準備したいのですが、意図通りに集計できません。`user_id` 毎の最新レコードを集計するというものです。

## 詳細

Statusという入退室モデルがあり、次のような構造をしています。

- Status

  - id
  - user_id
  - logged_in
  - logged_out
  - created_at
  - updated_at

各ユーザ (`user_id`) の最新レコード（最後に入室もしくは退室した時間）をviewでユーザ毎に表示させたいのですが、集計の方法がわかりません。

ご教示のほどよろしくお願いします。

## 動作環境

- Rails 4.2.5
- ruby 2.2.3

Answer (score 1):

サブクエリを作ることで user_id ごとに集計して、その中でlogged_in が最大の行を選択することができます。

```
Status
  .where(%{
    NOT EXISTS(
      SELECT 1
      FROM statuses s1
      WHERE statuses.user_id = s1.user_id AND
            statuses.logged_in < s1.logged_in
    )
  }).order(:user_id).pluck(:user_id, :logged_in)
```

これを実行すると、次のようなSQLクエリが実行されます。

```
SELECT *
FROM statuses
WHERE (
  NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM statuses s1
    WHERE statuses.user_id = s1.user_id AND
          statuses.logged_in < s1.logged_in
  )
)
```

※ARELを使って抽象化した方が良いのですが、テーブルを別名でサブクエリに入れる方法が分からない… (多分できない)

なお、`user_id` と `logged_in` の最大値だけを求めれば良いのであれば、イカのようなコードで取得は出来ます。この場合、`id` などが `nil` になりますので、気をつけてください。

```
Status
  .group(:user_id)
  .select("user_id, MAX(logged_in) AS logged_in")
```

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(logged_in) AS logged_in
FROM statuses
GROUP BY user_id
```

`user_id` と `logged_in` 以外のフィールドも欲しいと思って、イカのように書いてしまうとSQLの文法エラーになります。これは、`SELECT` 句には、`GROUP BY` に指定したフィールドと、集約関数以外は指定できないためです。

利用するRDBMSによってはエラーを返しませんが、**意図通りに動くかはマニュアルを参照してください**。

```
Status
  .group(:user_id)
  .select("*, MAX(logged_in) AS max_logged_in")
```

```
SELECT *, MAX(logged_in) AS max_logged_in
FROM statuses
GROUP BY user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

できれば使用しているRDBMSとサンプルデータ、それと期待する結果も載せてほしかったです。
とりあえず、「たぶんこういうことかな？」と想像しながら回答します。

まずこんなテストコードを書きました。

```
require 'test_helper'

class StatusTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "ユーザー別に最新のレコードを集計する" do
    alice = User.create!(name: 'Alice')
    bob = User.create!(name: 'Bob')

    alice_status_1 = alice.statuses.create!(
      logged_in: '2015-01-01 00:00:00', logged_out: '2015-01-01 01:00:00')
    alice_status_2 = alice.statuses.create!(
      logged_in: '2015-01-02 00:00:00', logged_out: nil) # <= 最新

    bob_status_1 = bob.statuses.create!(
      logged_in: '2015-01-01 00:00:00', logged_out: '2015-01-31 01:00:00') # <= 最新
    bob_status_2 = bob.statuses.create!(
      logged_in: '2015-01-02 00:00:00', logged_out: '2015-01-02 01:00:00')

    statuses = Status.latest_by_user.order(:user_id)
    assert_equal [alice_status_2, bob_status_1], statuses
  end
end
```

このテストコードが期待する結果と合っていれば、以下のようなコードで実装できます。

```
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  scope :latest_by_user, -> {
    sub_query = <<-SQL
SELECT user_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN logged_out IS NULL THEN logged_in ELSE logged_out END) AS max_datetime
FROM statuses
GROUP BY user_id
    SQL

    join_sql = <<-SQL
INNER JOIN (#{sub_query}) AS sub
ON sub.user_id = statuses.user_id
AND sub.max_datetime = CASE WHEN statuses.logged_out IS NULL THEN statuses.logged_in ELSE statuses.logged_out END
    SQL

    joins(join_sql)
  }
end
```

userd_idごとにlogged_inまたはlogged_outの最大時間を取得し（`sub_query`）、それをStatusのjoinの中で絞り込み条件にしています。（`join_sql`）

ときどき「生SQLは書きたくない！」という人を見かけますが、集計関数（SUM, MAX等）が絡んでくると急激にActiveRecordが書きにくくなるので、無理せずにSQLを書けばいいじゃないか、というのが僕の実装方針です。

動作確認に使用したのはSQLiteです。
標準SQLの範囲内だと思うのでPostgreSQLやMySQLでも動作すると思いますが、確認はしていません。

GitHubにコードもアップしたので、必要であれば手元で動かしてみてください。

https://github.com/JunichiIto/show-latest-sandbox

Answer (score 0):

集計というのが何を指しているのか分かりませんが、idがautoincrementなカラムでユーザの最新のデータを取得するだけであれば

```
Status.where(user_id: user_id).order(:id).reverse_order.limit(1)
```

で良いのでは無いかと思いますがいかがでしょうか？